# Rails prawn gem - multiple dispositions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, download, prawn

I am using the prawn gem in Rails to generate a PDF. Currently I am using `disposition: "inline"` to render the PDF in the browser (and in my view: `<%= link_to "PDF", product_path(@product, format: "pdf") %>`. Is there any way that I can have multiple dispositions so that in my view I could have one link that renders the PDF in the browser and a separate link that will automatically download the PDF?

Comment: you can insert link as you've specified to render the pdf, and call to a specific action of a controller, in which you have to send the pdf as a file.

Comment: Thanks, good point. If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert link as you've specified to render the **.pdf**, and call to a specific action of a controller, in which you have to send the *.pdf* as a file, for example with [`#send_file` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5d8faa683e230e6af54ac7616f98f3ae088e7682/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/data_streaming.rb#L67):

```
send_file '/path/to.pdf', type: 'document/pdf'
```